# Why does a rigid body sometimes have translational motion and sometimes rotational motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

If apply some force on a pencil, it rolls and moves in a straight line but if apply some force on its edges or somewhere from the centre, it rotates by some angle. Can you please explain why does this phenomenon occur?

$ \vec{\tau} = \vec{r} × \vec{F}$ maybe a reason for this, according to me. When $\vec{r} = 0$ , torque will be zero too, so no rotation. (Is this explanation correct?) But what will be the position with respect to which we measure $\vec{r}$ here? I mean how is the axis defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will there be translation + rotational motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295731/will-there-be-translation-rotational-motion) and the links therein.

Comment: Sometimes I steer my car straight. Other times I turn.